# How javascript allows object key type syntax without including ir inside a literal and also variable declaration inside it?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

While running these statement in chrome console or inside script tag what I found is that the below syntax which I thought is invalid is working and all the varaibles were exposed globally which I understand could be due to curly braces are interpreted as block but that key: in front is what confuse me. But I am not sure why and looking for an explaination.

```
    foo: {
      a = 5,
      b = 6
    }

    console.log(a) output --->  5
    console.log(b) output --->  6


    foo: {
      a = 5;
      b = 6;
    }

    console.log(a) output --->  5
    console.log(b) output --->  6


    foo: {
      a: 5;
      b: 6;
    }

    console.log(a) output --->  5
    console.log(b) output --->  6
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: thanks @jonrsharpe for the reference I was looking for same but was unable to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because *foo:* is interpreted as a label and your "ObjectLiteral" get's interpreted as block and the statements inside get executed.

Your code boils down to the following.

```
a = 5,
b = 6
```

Since you don't have any declaration like `var`, `let`, or `const` you're setting a global variable *a* and *b*

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a variable by just assigning to it  (without using `let`, `const`, `var` or as a function parameter), then it is global.

The labels do nothing because you have no loop to `continue` (or similar) from.

The blocks do nothing because you aren't using `let` or `const` which would scope variable to blocks.